# Google's OR-Tools for CVRP while minimizing global span

Tags: or-tools

I'm wondering how we can minimize the global span (makespan) in the CVRP context. I refer below:

```
distance_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)
```

AS a very simplified example, I try to solve the CVRP example (https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/cvrp) with the above *SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)*.

However, the results are not different with or without *SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)*.

I increased the number of vehicles to show the difference, but the increased vehicles are still idle. This is not adequate for the minimization of the global span.I also try to increase the large number (as like 100) to more larger number, but the solution is still unchanged.

How can I solve the CVRP while minimizing the global span?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure this is not the optimal solution ?

Answer (score 1):

By setting a non null coefficient (default) to the global span, you'll add it to the objective cost function which is minimized by the solver, so it is "already" minimized if it becomes the dominant factor (compare to the sum of arc cost)

note the example cvrp doesn't use local search...

```py
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
```

So you should try first to enable it.

e.g.

```py
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
    search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (
        routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH)
    search_parameters.time_limit.FromSeconds(30)
    search_parameters.log_search = True
```